# Facebook local currency

Tags: facebook, dialog, local, payment, currency-exchange-rates

I'm changing a facebook game from using facebook credits to the new user local currency model. Everything seems ok except the price that shows at facebook pay dialog. It shows an old price that I had defined before.

After I change the price in the product file, I upload it and re-scraped at [object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

No errors returned and the price array turned out ok.

```
{
   "amount": 3
   "currency": "USD"
}
```

My facebook account has set the payment currency in "EUR". So at the store the price should be returned in euros by the facebook callback. And it does, except for the value that comes out wrong in the facebook pay dialog.

Accordingly to facebook exchange rates the price shoud be 2.29€ (3 US dollars) instead it returns 1.99€

I don't know where this value is coming from. Do you have any idea?